# After publishing a program based on Windows Forms, the stimul soft file is not found

Tags: stimulsoft

After publishing a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) program the StimulSoft reporeter file not found.

My program is Windows application.

[Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy9h0.jpg)

Comment: Can you try to make your question comprehensible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't load your .mrt file correctly. Copy it in your .exe (Debug) folder and use this code:

```
 stiReport1.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\MyReport.mrt");
```